# Как привязать cookie к событию нажатия на блок?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookie

У блока меняются стили при нажатии на него:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.rating3').mouseup(function() {
        $(this).css('border', '1px solid #ff9999').css('background', '#ff0000');
    });
    $('.rating3 a').mouseup(function() {
        $(this).css('color', '#ffffff');
    });
});
```

Как привязать cookie к этому событию `mouseup`?

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.rating3').mouseup(function () {
        $(this).css('border','1px solid #ff9999').css('background','#ff0000');
        document.cookie = "Value1=1";
    });
    $('.rating3 a').mouseup(function () {
        $(this).css('color','#ffffff');
        document.cookie = "Value1=0";
    }); });
```

Смотрите,например, здесь более расширенно написано https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie

Просто смотря по Вашему коду, вы хотите каждую ссылку с классом rating3 привязать к событию. Это как-то немного странно-таким образом менять куку.  Тоесть если Вы клацните по одной ссылке с классом rating3, она запишет куку, а потом с другой ссылки с таким же классом-он опять запишет туже самую куку. Тоесть элементов с таким классом много, а кука в данном случае одна. Т.е. логики я не вижу в том, что Вы делаете

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, а Value1=1 и Value1=0 - это некий id? Не совсем понял, прошу простить.

Comment: Это название куки. Вы можете назвать её как хотите. Можете её просмотреть например в Chrom- прав кн мыши- Просмотр кода - Resources -Cookies

Comment: Прошу меня простить, но я не понимаю. Я заменил код, но он не работает.

Comment: Я проверил- кука добавляется. Лучше Вы конкретно опишите, зачем Вам при нажатии сохранять в куку? так вообще-то не делают

Comment: Это блок, где посетитель нажимает кнопку голосовать, чтобы при последующих заходах этот блок был закрашен другим цветом, соответственно чтобы посетитель видел где нажимал, а где нет.

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, а кроме замены этого кода, который я заменил, нужно видимо подключить еще какой-то файл скрипта?

Comment: А.....ну конечно. Думал-у Вас уже подключено, раз уж написали код под jquery. Это называется библиотека jquery,которая упрощает разработку(можете и другие использовать, но эта наиболее распространена и эта конструкция кода под неё) Качайте её от сюда например https://jquery.com/ -подключаете js файл к проекту- и вот тогда можете использовать её фишки

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду файл http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js ? Так он то конечно подключен. Сайт на dle. Или имеется ввиду другой какой-то файл?

Comment: Да.(или более новую версию).Значит тогда Вы не создали элемент с классом rating3, и не поместили в него элемент <a> . Должно работать всё. Только таким образом менять куку- так вообще не делают. Но для исследования-сделайте-должно работать. Если что- пишите

Comment: Нет, элемент с классом rating3 создан, и <a> в нем есть (<div class="rating3">[rating-plus]Голосовать {rating}[/rating-plus]</div>) Но тем не менее не работает.

Comment: <div class="rating3"><a href="#">Голосовать </a></div>   ???

Comment: да, в исходном коде получается такая конструкция: <div class="rating3"><a href="#" onclick="doRate('plus', '848'); return false;" >Голосовать <span id="ratig-layer-848" class="ignore-select"><span class="ratingtypeplusminus ignore-select ratingplus" >+1</span></span></a></div>

Comment: А если попробовать без return false ? или напишите onclick="doRate('plus', '848'); document.cookie ='Value1=1';return false;"   либо посмотрите в первой статье написали функцию setcookie.

Comment: Эту ссылку формирует сам скрипт DLE. Поэтому я и хотел, чтобы этот блок rating3, в который я и взял всю эту часть, при нажатии закрашивался в другой цвет. Он и закрашивается. И каким-то образом нужно сделать так, чтобы сохранялись куки именно этого блока rating3. Если у вас нет других соображений на этот счет, я тогда просто отмечу ваш ответ галочкой, и будем считать тогда его решенным.